# Optimize getting parameter values

Tags: java, performance

I would like to know if there's any difference of performance between these two ways of getting the parameter value in Java:

**Option 1:**

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    System.out.println(object.getName());
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
String name = object.getName();
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
   System.out.println(name);
}
```

Maybe with just 1 attribute (name), the option 2 is better, but, what if I would have 50 different attributes? I would be wasting memory storing those variables.

Please, think big, in a huge system with tons of users accessing to the WebApp.

Comment: The memory waste will be very tiny, just as the gain of performance. This is called micro-optimization, and you should not take it into account when developing (or only with _very_ specific cases). Compilers can do many things to optimize it better than you, and you will sacrifice readability for performance without even being sure to reach better performance. PS: yes, I think about big systems with thousands of concurrent users. Even there, you should not do that.

Comment: So, which option would you use? Or which of them do you usually use?

Comment: The one that is the most readable. Do not store temp variables to spare a call to a getter. Do store temp variable if you get them from an expensive call to a business method.

Comment: @spi you are saying contradictory things there: go with the most readable; and use a variable if you know it's an expensive call.

Comment: @Andy I should rephrase it as "write it the most readable you can. If you try to optimize something, then make measures of before and after the optimization"

Comment: What's more relevant than performance is that there's a semantic difference between the two in multithreaded environments, where the name might change during loop execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option should run `object.getName()` 1000 times, the other loop just once.

So, yes, obviously, there should be a certain performance impact. There is also a slight semantical difference: if that name isn't immutable, other threads might change it while that loop is running. Then option 2 *might* pick up that change at some random point in time, whereas option 1 will not do that.

Regarding the performance aspects: in Java, it is really hard to determine the effects of such subtle code changes. When that loop runs 100K times, the Just-in-time compiler would come in and translate everything into highly optimized machine code, using techniques such as method inlining, loop unrolling, constant folding, whatnot. It might even detect that `object.getName()` has no side effect, and thus turn your code into something that you put into your option 2 snippet. All of that happens at runtime, depending on the profiling information that the JVM collected for the JIT while running your code.

So, the typical answer regarding "java performance": avoid stupid mistakes (invoking a method that doesn't have side effects *inside* a loop would be such a mistake), but don't expect that someone could tell you "yeah, option 1 will run 500 ms faster". The "real" performance boosts in java are created by the JIT (and of course: clever designs for your implementation). Thus it is extremely hard to *predict* what this or that **source code** artefact will have at *runtime*.

And finally: please note that using `System.out.println()` is pretty expensive. So when your `getName()` really just fetches a property from memory, then the *printing* of that value to the console might be multiple times more expensive compared to fetching the values!

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated reply. The System.out.println() was a simplified way to explain it. What I want to say was that I call a lot of times to that method (getName).